# Connecting to MSSQL (on another machine) from Php in MAMP

Tags: php, sql-server, mamp

I am trying to connect to a MSSQL database on another machine (Windows 8.1 & SQL Server 2014 - Express) within the same network in Php using the mssql_connect function.

I have installed MSSQL into MAMP (it is present as an area in phpinfo();) and I have tested the credentials using the SQLPro for MSSQL (http://www.macsqlclient.com/) and it loads fine with SQLPro.

Although when connecting via mssql_connect keeps giving the error: " mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:"

I was wondering if I have missed anything? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue:
Even though FreeTDS was installed and running it was running the wrong version of TDS which stopped the connection.

I used the config (http://www.freetds.org/userguide/config.htm) to configure to the right Version that was needed (http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm)